# How to send a windows store app you're developing to a friend for easy testing

Tags: windows-store-apps, installation, share, windows-store

Hello I am trying to create a simple Windows Store app and want to send it to someone. I have packaged the app already. The question I have is how make this easy for the other person to install and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its Windows 8 Store app, to the folder where the app build is created. Go to the bin folder and there is a file called Add-AppDevPackage.ps1. Right click on it and click run with powershell.

Comment: actually is a 8.1 app. in the bin folder there was no such file. But in the folder generated from the packaging there is a folder called. AppPackages. tehre is a ps1 file in there but when I run it with power shell nothing happens.

Comment: There will be a file called Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 in apppackages folder

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm talking about.  It still doesn't do anything.